# Display Clickable list of a specific taxonomy in my custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I'm having a hard time even coming up with a title for this.

If I'm editing the code for a regulator old blog post (content.php) and add

```
<?php the_category(', ') ?>
```

I get a clickable list of all the categories that post belong to.

I have a custom post type called research and a custom taxonomy associated with it called topics. I'm editing content-research.php I just want the topics to show up the same way when looking at a research post.

I tried

```
<?php the_topic(', ') ?>
```

and that was a complete failure.

So I'm hoping there is a simple solutions because I have some additional taxonomies for this post type I'd like to add as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`the_category()` function only searches terms from the 'category' taxonomy as you can see in the core file https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9.2/src/wp-includes/category-template.php line 75

You could write your own function or you can use this snippet:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'taxonomyname' );

foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    echo '<a href="'.get_term_link($term->term_id).'">'.$term->name</a>.' ';
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, it add the links for the appropriate taxonomy, only issue is they all appear as "$term->name"

Comment: just needed a small tweak

Answer (score 1):

The answer from ovidiua2003 worked just needed this tweak.

```
      echo '<a href="'.get_term_link($term->term_id).'">'.$term->name.'</a> ';
```

So the whole thing would be

```
<?php 
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'taxonomy' );

foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
echo '<a href="'.get_term_link($term->term_id).'">'.$term->name.'</a>, ';
}
?>
```